# How do I prevent integer overflow when using C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, integer, overflow

http://ideone.com/hANuZ

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /**
     * Prints out powers of 2 for 32 iterations.
     */
    int iterations = 0;
    int value = 1;
    while (iterations <= 32) {
        // Prints in this format: iterations    2^n    value
        printf("%d\t2^%d\t%d", iterations, iterations, value);
        switch (iterations) {
          case 8:
          case 16:
          case 32:
              printf("\t\t%d bit\n", iterations);
              break;
          default:
              printf("\n");
              break;
        }
      value *= 2;
      ++iterations;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this piece of code, weird stuff happens when I print 'value' after it is larger than 2^30, even when I declare it as an unsigned long.

What do I do? I am simply a beginner. :-(

Comment: actually, this runs 33 iterations

Comment: maybe because I used ++iterations?

Comment: hmm.... 0-32 = 33. You initialize to 0 and loop until it is <= 32, thus it passes in the loop 33 times

Answer (score 4):

You are printing it like it is a signed integer.  try using the format string

```
"%u\t2^%u\t%u"
```

check your printf documentation for all of the formatting codes and what they do.  `%u` is for `unsigned int`.  `unsigned long` is generally `%lu`

Comment: this got rid of the - sign on 2^31 on the 31st iteration

Comment: only the last one may be `%u` the first two are the variable `iterations` and may be `%d` alright

Comment: @Sweetgirl17, 32nd iteration. Your first iteration is **0**, so when `iterations` is 31, you are at your 32nd one.

Comment: so for 32 bit integers, the range of values is -2^31 .. 2^31-1.  for 32 bit unsigned integers, the range is 0 .. 2^32-1.  -2^31 is the signed bit sequence 1 000....00 (first bit 1, everything else is 0).  however, that sequence happens to be 2^31 when interpreted as unsigned, which is why the "-" was removed.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer would be to try declaring it as an `unsigned long long` which is larger than 32 bits (minimum 64 bits according to the standard, thx @caf).

When dealing with types where the specific size is important though, you should use a type with a known size, like `int64_t`.

Comment: `unsigned long long` is *definitely* larger than 32 bits: it is required to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: @caf: I thought it just had to be bigger than `long`. Ta.

Comment: It only has to be equal or larger than `long`, and at least 64 bits.  Both `long` and `long long` being 64 bits is conforming, and in fact is common on 64 bit POSIX systems.

Comment: @caf: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited to include your info.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I did modify your code example a little for clarity

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitcount(unsigned long i) {
   int count = 0;
   while (i > 0) {
      count++;
      i>>=1;
   }
   return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   /**
    * Prints out powers of 2 for 32 iterations.
    */
   int iterations = 0;
   int value = 1;
   while (iterations <= 32) {
      // Prints in this format: iterations    2^n    value
      printf("%d\t2^%u\t%u\t\t%d bit\n", iterations+1, iterations, value, bitcount(value));
      value *= 2;
      ++iterations;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

You'll notice that `127` is `8 bit` and `256` is `9 bit`. This is because

```
127 =   1000 0000
256 = 1 0000 0000
```

Also, `2^32` is `0` because

```
2^32 = 1 0000 0000 ... 0000 0000       (overflow for int)
     =   0000 0000 ... 0000 0000 = 0   (only the first 32 bits are preserved)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need integer precision you need to use an external library for larger numbers.  For C GMP http://gmplib.org/ is a well known library.  If you don't need integer precision just use a float or a double.

If you're curious about what the limits are based on for types, this page is an ok read up http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html.